# Finding all connected computers to network and getting their IP adresses - Windows C

Tags: c, windows, networking, ip, winsock

just as title says.

Let's assume this situation:
I have a network and I need to know IP adresses and everything else related of all computers connected to mantain socket sending via Winsock under Windows.

Is there better way than looping throught IP Adresses range and sending something like:
"Are You there?" and waiting for answer from client?

Comment: Are you looked here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738533%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?

Comment: I think it won't work, I need to get informations before making any connections and from what I have read this function returns informations AFTER connected scoket. I need to scan whoel network in order to find ALIVE devices.

Is there anything easier than ARP scan?

Answer (score 0):

Performing an [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) scan would tell you which devices are active on the network, regardless of device type or operating system. So this would include PCs, laptops, phones, routers, and any other devices with a NIC. This is the most reliable way of scanning for live hosts on a network.

ARP is the protocol that translates IP addresses into MAC addresses, or vice versa. It allows routing devices to translate between the logical network and the physical network. When you send a packet to, say, 192.168.1.99, your system first sends out an ARP request for 192.168.1.99, saying something along the lines of "Who has 192.168.1.99? Tell [my MAC]". Other devices on the network see this packet, and the owner of that IP address will reply "Hi [MAC], I'm 192.168.1.99, my MAC is 00:12:34:56:78:90".

You can (ab)use this protocol to discover network devices. If you know you're on 192.168.1.x, you send ARP requests for 192.168.1.1 through 192.168.1.254, and record the results. Every reply you get indicates a live system at the defined IP address.

Keep in mind that not all your users will be on 192.168.1.0/24, so you'll need to check the current network configuration first.

As far as doing this in C goes, it's not a simple task. However, you can take a look at [this example](http://dl.packetstormsecurity.net/UNIX/misc/arp-scan.c) which implements ARP scanning.

Comment: Keep in mind that in an enterprise network, this is liable to set off alarms and could result in the computer's network connection being terminated.  Depending on your needs, passively listening to arp broadcasts may be a safer alternative.  (I'm fairly sure Windows also has some built-in discovery functionality, but I'm not familiar with it.)

Comment: Thank You guys for ideas but I decided to make a seperate server which is only keeping list of all connected PC to it and let them get needed information in order to transfer files.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the ARP scan suggested by @Polynomial is the [PING](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping) scan.

Same concept, PING each address in your subnet, and record the results.

Just as an ARP scan may give you false positives (because there is a router saying "I'll deal what that address" whether there is a device on it or not), so too, PING can give you false negatives (as some systems disable the ICMP/PING command).

There is a tool called [fping](http://fping.org/) that implements this kind of PING scan in a massively parallel way.  Fping is originally a *NIX program, but there are Windows versions out there.  You should be able to find the source to peruse if you want to learn the gory details.